# C# XPath Soap, how to navigate to embedded node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, xpath

In C#, Asp.Net, I am trying to return the Error node inside of BISearchResponse:
I am able to get the GetWireResult node returned in an XMLNode.
How do I get to the Error node?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
-     <soap:Body>
-          <GetWireResponse xmlns="http://OpenSolutions.com/">
                <GetWireResult><?xml version="1.0"?> 
                      <BISearchResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
                            <Error xmlns="https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0"> 
                                   <Message>BI System: Failed to Login</Message> 
                                   <Code>536870917</Code>
                             </Error>
                      </BISearchResponse>  
                </GetWireResult> 
            </GetWireResponse>
       </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

My code:
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

```
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(result);

            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://OpenSolutions.com/");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("bg", " https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            XmlNode xmlnode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse", nsmgr);
```

This works to here.
.
I am adding the xml here, but it is only visible in edit mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <soap:Body>
- <GetWireResponse xmlns="http://OpenSolutions.com/">
  <GetWireResult><?xml version="1.0"?> <BISearchResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <Error xmlns="https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0"> <Message>BI System: Failed to Login</Message> <Code>536870917</Code> </Error> </BISearchResponse></GetWireResult> 
  </GetWireResponse>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I put your XML sample into a {code} section. Please do this next time, or the XML doesn't show up (properly).

Comment: In edit mode, paste in your XML, then select it and press the "{}" button. You'll see the code show up in the preview. Then save. The code will now display correctly outside of edit mode.

Comment: It would help too if you would indent it so that the hierarchical structure is easy to see.

Comment: I think, content inside SOAP body `<GetWireResult>` is encoded XML, so it isn't part of XML.

Comment: since that is encoded xml, would one approach be to unencode it, load it into an xmlDocument object and continue parsing?

Comment: Why not? Provide your XML, and we can answer exactly. It's my supposition only.

Comment: @polishchuk - good insight. @user, are you copying and pasting the XML from a browser view? Try saving it to a file, so you can get another perspective on what's in it.

Comment: the xml returned is from a debugging session in VS 2010, I have trapped the result from the POST in var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

Comment: can either or all try putting that xml in a variable then try to navigate to the Error node?   Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What you've posted is not well-formed XML. The initial hyphen after the prologue looks like part of a tree view. If it's really in the data, it's broken XML, because text is not allowed outside the top-level element. And as mentioned below, the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` is not legal in the middle of an XML document. In this form, no one can put it into a variable in any sane XML processing tool.

Answer (score 1):

In debug mode, when you copy this XML, try choose another debug visualizer, e.g. "Text visualizer". You can select it clicking the magnifying glass icon in datatip.

I think your XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWireResponse xmlns="http://OpenSolutions.com/">
      <GetWireResult>
        &lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
        &lt;BISearchResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
        &lt;Error xmlns="https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0">
        &lt;Message>BI System: Failed to Login&lt;/Message&gt;
        &lt;Code>536870917&lt;/Code&gt;
        &lt;/Error&gt;
        &lt;/BISearchResponse&gt;
      </GetWireResult>
    </GetWireResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWireResponse xmlns="http://OpenSolutions.com/">
      <GetWireResult>
        <![CDATA[
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <BISearchResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <Error xmlns="https://bixg.choicepoint.com/webservices/3.0">
            <Message>BI System: Failed to Login</Message>
            <Code>536870917</Code>
          </Error>
        </BISearchResponse>
        ]]>
      </GetWireResult>
    </GetWireResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

No matter. So you can select `GetWireResult` using following XPath:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse/ab:GetWireResult
```

and then load it content in new XML document and get desired response.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Extend your XPath

```
"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse"
```

to

```
"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse/ab:GetWireResult/ab:BISearchResponse/bg:Error"
```

However that extra XML prologue stuck in there in the middle, `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, makes the XML not well-formed. I'm surprised it can be processed at all. I would think the C# API should throw an exception on `xmlDoc.LoadXml(result)`.

Another approach, seeing as the above does not return anything for you, would be to use your C# code to explore the structure of the XML document and print out the children of each node. E.g. if you are getting a node for `"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse"` but not for `"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse/ab:GetWireResult"`, does `ab:GetWireResponse` have what text node children, and if so, what are their values (contents)? That should give insight into why the XPath is not working.

If there's a block of unparsed (i.e. escaped) XML in there, you could either copy it out and parse it as XML like you said, or just search for the pattern you need using a regexp... depending on the complexity.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't return anything when I do that

Comment: @user: If the problem is that the stuff inside `<ab:GetWireResult>` is actually escaped (even though it's not showing that way, in the form that you pasted in) then you should get a result for `"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse/ab:GetWireResult"` and not for `"/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse/ab:GetWireResult/ab:BISearchResponse". Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: actually, I do not get a result for ab:GetWireResult nor ab:GetWireResult/ab:BISearchRespon‌​se   . I only get a result for /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ab:GetWireResponse

Comment: @user: please try saving the XML to a file, copy it from there and post it here (in your question). I'm assuming you had copied it from a browser view.

Comment: the xml returned is from a debugging session in VS 2010, I have trapped the result from the POST in var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);  So it is not from a browser.

Comment: Who is creating this POST data? The XML is not well-formed. As I suspected, an xml processing-instruction in the middle of a document is not allowed (it's a reserved word). Whoever created this POST data needs to remove the XML prolog in the middle of it.